# Use of same product key in Windows 7 different version

Tags: windows-7, windows, product-key

I'm using Windows 7 Home version. Recently I switched to Windows 7 Ultimate. Can I use the same product key that was given for Windows 7 Home version in newly installed Windows 7 Ultimate?

If so, can I switched back product key again to Windows 7 Home in future.

Comment: Simply put, no. Key's are tied to SKUs so a new SKU will require a new Key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK each key is only valid for its specific version. (and possibly it's architecture, not sure about this one)

Example : If you upgrade from W7 Home to W7 Professional you need to buy a new key.

So no, it not a valid solution.

Answer (score 3):

No, You can not buy a `Windows 7 Home Premium` license for $80 and then use it for a `Windows 7 Ultimate` installation where the license normally costs $380

But you can use [Windows Anytime Upgrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Anytime_Upgrade) provided you have a `Windows 7 Ultimate` license key.

Comment: Wait... Shouldn't you be saying you can use windows anytime upgrade provided you have a valid win7 home premium key?   If you have a win7 ultimate lisc already what would you be upgrading to?  @ramhound

Comment: @Tyson - If you have a `Windows 7 Home Premium` installation you can then upgrade that installation to `Windows 7 Ultimate`, provided you have a `Windows 7 Ultimate` license key.  The process to upgrade a Home Premium installation to Windows 7 Ultimate is not free.

Comment: I understand what you mean now... I was aware it wasn't free but the wording tripped me up. @Ramhound